# $\mathbb{R}$ written as union of open intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Is $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-n,n)?$

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Have you tried to prove it?

Comment: Is it true that for any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ there exists a natural $\;n\;$ s.t. $\;x\in (-n,n)\;$ ? Well, there you have your answer...

Comment: Try showing containment both ways..

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in R$ choose $n=[x+1]$ then $x\in (-n,n)$ where [] denotes nearest integer function ....

Comment: And can you also say that $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup [z, z+1], z\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @user54297: Yes,for any $x\in R$ choose $z=[x]$ then $x\in [z,z+1]$.